# How to bring dropdown at top

Tags: azure-devops, vssdk

[image]

I'm not  getting this dropdown in front as i have created a custom control combo of tree behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

By reference to this doc: [Add a custom field to a work item type (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops), we can add a custom field to support tracking data requirements you have that aren’t met with the existing set of fields.

Currently, the field `Area Path` and `Iteration Path` are existed datatype as Tree path, but their value are defined in Project configuration page and Team configuration page by reference to this doc: [Define area paths and assign to a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) and [Define iteration paths and configure team iterations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).

However, tree type is not available in new field, as below.
[image]

In addition, this is indeed a good suggestion. You can create a suggestion ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion). The product group will review these tickets regularly, and consider take it as roadmap.

Comment: Hi Harsh, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.